# Get all site collection in tenant using SharePoint Office 365 app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, app, office-web-apps

Hi i am creating Office 365 SharePoint APP(SharePoint Hosted).

Now i need to get **all site collection of tenant** in my office 365 app.

How to a get all site collection using JSOM (According to my knowledge i can use only JavaScript in SharePoint App).

Or can i use CSOM on SharePoint Office 365 apps? I found a blog [Here](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2014-4-Get_list_of_site_collections_using_CSOM_in_Office365.aspx) to get all site collection using CSOM.

Please help me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569281/what-is-the-rest-endpoint-url-to-get-the-list-of-site-collections-in-sharepoint

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by the following script in CSOM

```
SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable spp = null;
var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
int startIndex = 0;

while (spp == null || spp.Count > 0)
{
    spp = tenant.GetSiteProperties(startIndex, true);
    ctx.Load(spp);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (SiteProperties sp in spp)
        siteCols.Add(new SiteCol(sp.Title, sp.Url));

   startIndex += spp.Count;
}
```

Please, see:
http://sprecipe.com/2015/11/04/sharepoint-online-retrieve-all-site-collections-via-csom/
or 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405584/sharepoint-csom-retrieving-site-collections-limited-to-300/24406495#24406495